# CSS Sprite Problems

Tags: css, css-sprites

I'm trying to setup some CSS sprites, they all function the same, except each one has a  different background. This works fine in every browser in OS X but does not work in Firefox for Windows and Linux or IE. The part in particular that does not work is the hovering.

CSS

```
    .sprite {
        background-position: 0px 0px;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 25px;
        width: 80px; 
        height: 86px;
        float: left;
    }

    .sprite.videos { 
        background: url('images/button-videos-sprite.png') no-repeat top left; 
    } 

    .sprite.music { 
        background: url('images/button-music-sprite.png') no-repeat top left; 
    } 

    .sprite.twitter { 
        background: url('images/button-twitter-sprite.png') no-repeat top left; 
    } 

    .sprite.facebook { 
        background: url('images/button-facebook-sprite.png') no-repeat top left; 
    } 

    .sprite:hover { 
        background-position: 0px -86px; 
    }
```

HTML

```
            <a href="...">
                <div class='sprite videos'></div>
            </a>

            <a href="...">
                <div class='sprite music'></div>
            </a>

            <a href="...">
                <div class='sprite facebook'></div>
            </a>

            <a href="...">
                <div class='sprite twitter'></div>
            </a>
```

**EDIT**

I just upgraded from FF 4 to 8 and everything works in FF now, but IE, not a chance. One thing I'm confused about is that this line must come at the end, even on Chrome:

```
    .sprite:hover { 
        background-position: 0px -86px; 
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: can you attach the image? FYI: http://draeton.github.com/stitches/

Comment: Looks like it should work... good old cross-browser compatibility! 1) Are you using a doctype, and 2) can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and confirm whether it still doesn't work cross-browser?

Comment: Im pretty sure you need to put spaces after each class in your css... so ".sprite.facebok" should be........ ".sprite .facebook"

Comment: @MichaelRader `.sprite.facebook` selects an element with both classes, while `.sprite .facebook` selects an element with `.facebook` that is a descendant of an element with `.sprite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version you're using the problem could be that you are trying to use `:hover` on a div `<div>` and not a link `<a>`.

Comment: *slaps forehead* That was it! I took out the divs and just used the anchor tags. Works all the way back to IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing your css as follows:

```
.sprite {
    background: transparent none no-repeat 0px 0px; /* full shorthand */
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: 80px; 
    height: 86px;
    float: left;
}
```

And then for each `.sprite.xxxx` block do:

```
.sprite.videos { 
    background-image: url('images/button-videos-sprite.png'); /* override just the background-image... */
    background-position: top left; /* ... and the background-position */
}
```

And leave the `.sprite:hover` block intact:

```
.sprite:hover { 
    background-position: 0px -86px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `<div>` element inside of an `<a>` element. This is one of the validations problems with your code. The correct approach is to put the `<a>` inside of the `<div>`:

```
<div><a href="#"></a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I just ended up doing away with the `<div>` altogether and using stylesheet properties on the anchor tag.